# Global action of lightning component Type is not visible in Lightning Community tile menu

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community, global-actions

I wish to add a global action in lightning Community page. I have created a global action that refers to a custom lightning Component named “Customer Search” and added the specified permissions to my user’s profile. Although when I tried to add my global action to navigation tile menu, the desired Action is not visible. Are there any ideas of what is going wrong?

[image]

[image]

My Component starts with the following:

```
<aura:component controller="CustomerSearchController" 
implements=" flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickAction,forceCommunity:searchInterface" access="global" >
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See these troubleshooting steps "Unable to see global or quick actions" Knowledge Article Number    000340216

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000340216&type=1&mode=1

**Edit:**

Does your object use record types and is the testing user able to access them? See “Default Global Actions: A Special Case”  help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=actions_and_record_types.htm&type=5

If so, then as of april 27, 2020:

> Default Global Actions: A Special Case
>
> If you have default global actions in your organization and you’re
>   using record types, your users might not be able to see all the
>   default actions that are assigned to a page layout.
>
> Default global actions are assigned to the Master record type, which
>   isn’t accessible to most profiles. As a result, default global actions
>   with the Master record type that are associated with target objects
>   that have record types configured aren’t available for most users. To
>   fix this issue, edit the default global actions associated with those
>   objects and reassign them to a different record type.
>
> For example, the New Contact default global action has Contact as its
>   target object. Let’s say you have record types set up for the Contact
>   object, and you add the New Contact default global object to a page
>   layout. Users who visit records based on that page layout don’t see
>   the New Contact action because the action is assigned to the Master
>   record type by default. Editing the New Contact default global action
>   and assigning it to a record type other than Master makes it available
>   for all users who have access to its assigned record type.

Comment: Hi Peter and thank you for your answer. The case is not that i cannot see the Action. I can see the global action within Salesforce, however i cannot see it as a Global Action in my Partner Community Builder.

Comment: I added Edits to the answer.  See the part about "record type".